# Maxcut in NetworkX is not found

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to import maxcut module from networkx and keep getting

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx.algorithms.approximation.maxcut'

```
import networkx.algorithms.approximation.maxcut as maxcut

maxcut.randomized_partitioning(G, seed=4269, p=0.5, weight=weight)
```

[NetworkX randomized_partitioning documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.maxcut.one_exchange.html#networkx.algorithms.approximation.maxcut.one_exchange)

Comment: What version of network are you using?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco I am using 2.5 I'll update and try again that for pointing that out